# Unable to change the user-agent in Silverlight C#. how I can do it?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am tring to fetch the html page and want to put my header into request. I tried to do this code.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 WebHeaderCollection coll = new WebHeaderCollection() { { "user-agent", "test" } };
 client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
 string url = API_URL + pagenum;
 client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

This code is invalid because http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection.aspx don't have add function.

```
client.Headers["user-agent"] = "xyz"
```

This is also not work. I tried and got error like user-agent can not be modified. Someone can tell me How to fix it.

I don't see anything that can help me. If this have duplicate here. Point to me that post.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the [Silverlight WebHeaderCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) user-agent is listed as a restricted field that you cannot change, so it appears that there is no way to change it.

> Some common headers are considered restricted and are either exposed
>   directly (such as Content-Type) or protected by the system and cannot
>   be set or changed in a WebHeaderCollection object. Any attempt to set
>   one of these restricted headers in the WebHeaderCollection object
>   associated with a HttpWebRequest object throws an exception. Any
>   attempt to set one of these restricted headers in the
>   WebHeaderCollection object associated with a WebClient object will
>   throw an exception later when attempting to send the WebClient
>   request.
>
> Many of these restricted headers are set by the web browser that hosts
>   the Silverlight application.